# How to make microcontroller such as Raspberry Pi external interruption handler for an antenna device?

Tags: microcontroller, antenna, wireless, signal-processing

I am pretty new to microcontroller, and I want to make wireless device, that actually consists of two devices:

One has a button, another has a led - when the button of the first device is pressed and holds, it sends a signal via (for example half-wave dipole) antenna, but not via WiFi, and other device, receiving that signal should turn on the led. When the button is released the second device offs the led.

Obviously for external interruptions one will add a handler to the loop function of the microcontroller, checking some of GPIOs values:

```
void loop()
{
    if(GPIO[0] == true)
       // Do something
}
```

It, probably will work fine for handling button press, however, when the em wave is passing through the device, because of its high speed (300 000 000 m/s), device could just run another line of code at that moment, while the wave is passing through, so some data will be lost.

Can someone provide books or other information of how to make such device, with own antenna and data generation\sending?

Comment: the raspberry pi is not a microcontroller.   you simply read the documentation for the mcu in question (make sure you check the electrical specs for the shape/frequency of signal it can detect).

Comment: @old_timer if raspberry pi is not a microcontroller, what is it?

Comment: Raspi pico is a microcontroller, raspi is a microprocessor. What you’re describing sounds like a remote control. Why confuse things with EM waves, speed of propagation and external interrupts?  There are plenty of examples on the interwebs using cheap 433MHz modules to send and receive the EM waves. Is this what you are wanting?

Comment: The raspberry pi is a computer with a full on processor, dram, etc.   not an mcu.

Comment: @Kartman, yeah I Pico is microcontroller. I don't know about modules, how can I google for it?

Comment: @old_timer, is not Raspberry Pi Pico a microcontroller, rather than a "computer"?

Comment: Google 433MHz modules. Then add Arduino to it. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a radio receiver between your receive antenna and the microcontroller.  The receiver can be designed to produce a digital "High" as long as it is receiving a signal from your transmitter.

You will also need a transmitter between your button and the transmit antenna - the button could turn the transmitter on and off when pressed/released.

The speed of propogation of a radio signal is irrelevant for your application.